How to get the usernames of all administrators within a supergroup from list of supergroups links
I have a list of links (approximately 11K) which are supergroups.
And I need to get username of every administrator from each supergroup.
I tried to do this with searchPublicChat and getSupergroupMembers,
but I keep getting error 429 (too many requests).
Can we get rid of this error?
Or maybe there is another way to implement this?
